# Node.js - How do you control Async callback sequence?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

In the following example I am walking over a directory tree to obtain a listing of directories and files. Importantly I need the order of directories and files to be the same as you would visually look at them in a file explorer. For brevity I am just writing out the folders and files to console.log in the sequence I would expect them...

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var walk = function(dir) {
    console.log(dir);
    var files = [];
    var items =  fs.readdirSync(dir).sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
    });
    items.forEach(function(item){
        if (item.charAt(0) !== '.') {
            var itemPath = path.join(dir,item);
            if (fs.lstatSync(itemPath).isDirectory()) {
                walk(itemPath);
            } else {
                files.push(itemPath);
            }
        }
    });
    files.forEach(function(file){
        console.log(file);
    });
};

walk('c:\\foo\\bar');
```

This Sync version took all of 20 minutes to develop and enforces the exact sequence that I need.

Turning this into an Async solution is a great example of how making Node.js "scalable" can quickly become verbose, complex and time consuming over other languages.

Whilst I would be interested in how others would solve this in a pure way (enforcing sequence), I am really interested in how other developers are using boiler plate libraries for this type of problem.

There seems to be numerous solutions on NPM that have all adopted their own implementation. Without taking the time to learn them all, I am not sure which one to pick.

The bottom line question... How would you turn the above code into an Async solution whilst enforcing callback sequence. Examples would be helpful. If you use a boiler plate library, why did you choose it. I would be interested to hear other people comments, in particular around the style and readability of the various solutions.

**Update 1**

I need to enforce the callback sequence of async events that are happening within a recursive function. This is not to be confused with enforcing call back sequence of nested callbacks that can be solved with promises, e.g. then().then().then()...

What I need to happen is for the recursive walk() function to only fire one at a time, such that the next walk() effectively waits for the previous walk() to complete. I say "effectively waits" as an idea of what should happen, but obviously making the code "really wait" would imply pausing the code which is also not the right solution.

Although I wonder if a solution that somehow implements process.nextTick() to park the next walk() could be one direction to look at.

Answer (score 1):

Why shouldn't be using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) when it comes to async operations

Simplified, customized version of [bluebird example](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#mapfunction-mapper--object-options---promise)

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var join = Promise.join;
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs"));
var path = require("path")

var walk = function(dir){
    return fs.readdirAsync(dir).map(function(fileName) {
        var file = path.join(dir, fileName);
        var stat = fs.statAsync(file);
        return join(stat, function(stat) {
            return {
                stat: stat,
                fileName: file
            }
        });
    }).call("sort", function(a, b) {
        return a.fileName.localeCompare(b.fileName);
    }).each(function(file) {
        if(file.stat.isDirectory()){
            walk(file.fileName);
        }
        console.log(file.fileName + " last modified " + file.stat.mtime)
    })
}

walk('./');
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have ran your code and the sequence is not the same as the sync version.

Comment: Ahh, just realised, you have cut and paste the example from Bluebird. I will try and get my head around the solution. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks again for the response, but this does not answer my question.

Promisify'ing an Async solution with bluebird sugar does not enforce call back sequence.

From what I can tell, the promise generated by bluebirds abstraction of fs.readdirSync is "still" a callback function that gets processed Asynchronously.

That means the we get a race condition between the mapped recursion calls. Essentially they will finish out of sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I revisted this problem and came up with the following solution...

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var sorter = function (a, b) {
    return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
}

var readdirAsync = function(dir) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve,reject) {
        fs.readdir(dir,function(err,dirs) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
            } else {
                resolve(dirs)
            }
        })
    })
}

var walker = function(dir) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve,reject) {
        var depth = 0;
        var fileTree = [];
        var sortHack=Array(50).join('Z')+':';
        var walk = function(dir) {
            var files = [];
            depth++;
            fileTree.push(dir);
            readdirAsync(dir).then(function(dirs) {
                dirs.forEach(function(item){
                if (item.charAt(0) !== '.') {
                        var itemPath = path.join(dir,item);
                        if (fs.lstatSync(itemPath).isDirectory()) {
                            walk(itemPath);
                        } else {
                            var parts=itemPath.split('/');
                            parts.push(sortHack + parts.pop());
                            files.push(parts.join('/'));
                        }
                    }
                });
                files.forEach(function(file){
                    fileTree.push(file);
                });
                depth--;
                if (depth===0) {
                    fileTree.sort(sorter);
                    for (var n=0;n<fileTree.length;n++) {
                        fileTree[n] = fileTree[n].replace(sortHack,"")
                    }
                    resolve(fileTree);          
                }

            },function(reason){reject(reason)}).catch(function(reason){reject(reason)});
        }
        walk(dir);
    });
}

var start = new Date().getTime();
walker('/home').then(function(tree){
    console.log(tree);
    var took = new Date().getTime() - start;
    console.log(took + 'ms')
},function(reason){
    console.log("something went wrong :( " + reason);
}).catch(function(reason){
    console.log("something went very wrong :S " + reason);
});
```